# Should I take the side of the poor oppressed Duergar, or the racist Genies in the Civil Rights Negotiation?

Tags: shut-up-and-jam-gaiden

I've been asked to mediate a civil rights dispute between a striking band of Duergar who are being deprived of their Dunkaroos and Rubies, and a conspiracy of racist Genies working on behalf of the Square-Enix-Goya Corporation who wish to deprive the dwarves of their Civil Rights at all costs and get maximum yields from the Chupa Mines.

Now I already know that there's no benefit to trying to reach a compromise - there are only rewards for choosing a side. What I'm not sure of is just how the rewards: Armor and a +50 VP potion from the dwarves or (less useful) armor and a Wish from Kazaam; stack up against each other.

Which is the better choice?

Comment: I don't even... wat...

Comment: Two things: first, does this Kazaam have a Shaq-esque appearance? Secondly, this made me miss dunkaroos.

Comment: @Fluttershy Not just Shaq-esque. It *is* Shaq.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That settles it! I am playing this game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal choice is almost certainly to side with the Genies in all matters *except* for the ban on elixirs - those should be completely legalized.

Relaxing the ban on the elixirs does not forfeit your reward for negotiating in the Genies favor if you conduct the rest of the negotiations in the most one-sided manner possible (the last option to every other question), but *does* allow you to get the **Mysterious Potion** from the dwarf who asks at what range you can smell his brews. This yields +50 VP to any one character.

The armor reward for siding with the Genies, the **Falcon Jodhpurs** is the best armor in the game for Balthios - by an equally large margin to the armor the Dwarves award to Barkley - and he needs the extra guard to compensate for his low HP and otherwise weak Guard stat.

Additionally, siding with the Genies grants you a magic lamp and a wish from Kazaam -  if you wish for **Power**, all of your characters will gain **+5 to all stats**.

By contrast, siding with the Dwarves yields the **Shrekimono**, the best armor in the game for the Barkleys -  however, while Hoopz could certainly use the +10 Guard vs the Mithril Jersey, the +5 from Kazaam combined with the benefit of the Jodhpurs for Balthios *and* the bonuses to all other stats are clearly the superior choice. Unless, y'know, you've got one of those conscience things. Which you shouldn't. It's every man for himself in the post-cyberpocalypse after all.

Comment: For some reason the only words I can see in this answer are "you should play this game"

Comment: @Tacroy Good news! It's available [as a free download for both Windows and OS X](http://www.talesofgames.com/related_game/barkley-shut-up-jam-gaiden/)!